# Spring DAO test (how to specify location of sqlite db file)

Tags: spring, sqlite, testing

I'm using Spring 4 and I've a JUnit test which uses jdbc template to persist data to an sqlite 3 database (which is essentially a file in my case called test.db on the file system). My test works fine and does persist to the database file successfully.

I'm using Maven to build and when I run my Junit test it creates the test.db file in the root folder of the project (i.e. in the same directory where the pom.xml file is). I would like to ensure this file gets created in the target/ directory instead and referenced in there.

Is there a way in a spring test that i can tell spring where to "create" this test.db file?

Any help would be great -
Thanks Ro

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in one of your files you should have a path variable to the database. This is probably in our JDBC template file. It should look something like this:

DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();  dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby:c:\temp\database\test01;create=true");

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SpringJDBC/article.html